# Element after div coming in next line in Mozilla firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox

I have a text box within a DIV & a button outside div. I need both (text box & button) to be in the same line. In Internet Explorer both are coming in same line. But, in Mozilla, button is coming in next line. Attached are the screenshots.

Images:
[image: Viewed in Mozilla]
[image: Viewed in IE]

aspx/HTML code:

```
<div class="fileInputs">
<asp:FileUpload class="hiddenFile" ID="fucAttachment" runat="server" onmouseout="copyContents('fucAttachment');" />
<div class="visibleField">
    <input type="text" readonly="readonly" id="visibleAttachmentField" style="width: 158px; height: 18px; margin-left: -4px;" />
</div>
<input type="button" class="browseBtn" value="Browse"/>
```

CSS:

```
 div.fileInputs
    {
        position: relative;
        z-index: 0;
    }
    .hiddenFile
    {
        position: relative;
        text-align: right;
        -moz-opacity: 0;
        filter: alpha(opacity: 0);
        opacity: 0;
        z-index: 2;
        width: 220px;
        /*cursor: pointer; cursor: hand; */
    }
    .visibleField
    {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0px;
        left: 0px;
        z-index: 1;
        margin-left: 4px;
        display: inline-block;            
    }
    .browseBtn, .uploadBtn
    {
        cursor: pointer;
        float: RIGHT;
        position: ABSOLUTE;
        margin-left: -60PX;
        height: 20px;
        font-size:12px;
        font-family: Arial;
        padding-left: 6px; 
        padding-right: 6px;
        border:1px solid #768ea5; 
        background-image: none;
        background-color: rgb(214,211,206);
    }
```

Comment: Please show the _actual_ HTML code – anything server-side is of no interest when discussing a client-side problem.

Comment: Nothing related to server side. Its purely an alignment issue, some CSS problem. Its happening only in Mozilla.

Comment: Also your button CSS has both position:absolute and float:right; You shouldn't do that.

Comment: _“Nothing related to server side”_ – yes, I know – that’s why I asked you _not_ to post server-side code (ASP), but the HTML code the client actually receives.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you put the button inside div.

Put both inputs float left. If your container div will be positioned absolute you will need to give also width to the container div.

If you need text/input not to be visible just target that not the whole div.